# Sitecore 8.1 update 2 production health check

Tags: xdb, mongodb, health-monitor

Sitecore healthcheck.aspx checks connection to all DBs mentioned in connectionString.config.

I want to test

- If analytics data being captured or not in MongoDB replication set
- Processing Server working properly by testing MongoDB data being pushed to  SQL Analytics DB or not.

*I dont want to test those by altering timeout in configuration file as it is Live environment.*
What is the best possible way to test above scenarios in Sitecore 8.1 Update 2

Answer (score 2):

One possible way of checking off both these items is to look at the MongoDB database `tracking_live` which has a collection called `ProcessingPool`.  When sessions are ended, or various other activities encountered, Sitecore uses this collection to specify work for the processing server to do. When the processing server is running it will poll this collection and remove work items as they are completed.

If you monitor the state of this collection over the course of 30s by requesting all the data every 5s, you should be able see items being added and removed.  Ideally the 'natural state' of this collection is zero items (as Sitecore Processing server has processed all the items).  If there are a large number of items, your processing server isn't processing.  If nothing goes in, your Sitecore CDs are probably not closing sessions out properly.